# Fragment not attached to activity on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

First let me explain the flow of my app.

I've got a `MainActivity` that extends a `DrawerActivity`. This `DrawerActivity` is responsible for managing two `drawers`. One on the left and one on the right.

`MainActivity` starts a fragment with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.activity_base_container, initialFragment, initialFragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
```

In that `initialFragment` the user is presented with some buttons. One of them is a fragment that displays a map. If the user presses the button I'm doing this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentMap fragment = (FragmentMap) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentMap.class.getSimpleName());

if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = FragmentMap.newInstance();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.activity_base_container, fragment)
        .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
        .commit();
}

FragmentRightDrawer fragmentRightDrawer =
    (FragmentRightDrawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentRightDrawer.class.getSimpleName());

if (fragmentRightDrawer == null) {
    fragmentRightDrawer = FragmentRightDrawer.newInstance(fragment);
}

((DrawerActivity) getActivity()).enableRightDrawer(fragmentRightDrawer);
```

When the map is visible on the screen, the user can open the right drawer, push a button and a marker is drawn on the map. At the ame time the drawer is closed.
As you can see, the right drawer is disabled by default and must be enabled. In `FragmentRightDrawer.newInstance(fragment);` I'm passing the map callback so I can receive the event when the user presses the button in the right drawer. Since the right drawer is actually a recyclerview with a list of buttons, I'm also passing this map callback to the recyclerview adapter.

In my `FragmentMap` I have the method `setMarker(int buttonID);` that will receive the id of the button the user clicked.

The adapter will call `mMapListener.setMarker(buttonID);`

This is working as expected. The problem is when I rotate the screen. The map is recreated and is visible in the screen. The right drawer is also recreated and I can open it. The problem is when I click the button. I then get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentMap{425e92b0} not attached to Activity`.

I believe that this is happening because the `mMapListener` callback has a reference to an "old" `FragmentMap`.

Whats the best way to handle this?

Comment: Are you using setRetainInstance(true) in both the fragments? Otherwise your fragments will get destroyed and recreated.

Comment: @brainfreak Thanks. Nope. I was not. I've set `setRetainInstance(true)` in `FragmentMap` and know I do not get the error and `FragmentMap` receives the button click. But I know have another problem. After rotating the screen and opening the right drawer and clicking the button, the drawer does not close. Before rotating the screen I was doing `if (mNavigationDrawer.isDrawerOpen(drawer)) {
            mNavigationDrawer.closeDrawer(drawer);
        } else {
            mNavigationDrawer.openDrawer(drawer);
        }` and it was closing.

Comment: Use a simple variable in your FragmentMap to create that logic instead of mNavigationDrawer. This would preserve the state of the drawer on rotate.

Comment: @brainfreak Ok. Will try that. But if I do not want to use setRetainInstance and want to handle all the stuff myself?

Comment: Use the onSaveInstanceState callback to store your stuff and get it from onCreateView after rotation.